# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined thrown (jasmine)

Tags: javascript, typescript, karma-jasmine

This is error in Jasmine Testing:

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined thrown\nUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined thrown**

code:

```
getReports(form){
  this.requestService.postRequest('DB', 'detailEvent', {'form': form, 'table': typeTemp.table, 'actionReport': tipoTemp.action}).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.events = data.events.length ? data.events : [];
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
 };
```

My test:

```
it('Should call requestService.postRequest', () => {
  spyOn(component.requestService, 'postRequest').and.returnValue(of({events:[]));
  let form = {};
  component.getReports(form);
  expect(component.requestService.postRequest).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.requestService.postRequest).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

data.events can be undefined. You need to do something like `(data.events || []).length` or `data.events?.length || 0` (latest ecmascript).